# How to clone all public repositories from gitlab server?

Tags: gitlab

There is an unstable gitlab server and I am not sure that it will be able to work in the future. Therefore, I want to make a backup copy of **all the repositories (projects)** that are there.

Cloning the source code will be enough, but it will be great if there is a way to save issues as well. Are there any ways to do this?

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/backup_restore.html

Comment: As I understand it, this is only available to server administrators. The problem is that I am not:(but I am a gitlab server user)

Comment: What about going to Settings -> General -> Export project? https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/import_export.html

Comment: This is already better, because it allows you to save not only the source code. But as I understand it, it helps to download only my projects, and not the projects of all users that are visible, for example, in gitlab.example.com/explore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kind of access you have, but if you don't have administrator access [to do a full backup](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/backup_restore.html), then the best thing to do is to use a couple of API endpoints to get the information you need and go from there.

1. Use the [Projects API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects) to get a list of all projects accessible to you.

   - Note the pagination limits.
   - What you store depends on how you want to get the information.
   - Store at least the ID number of each.
   - Filter by `membership` if you only want the ones you're a member of.
   - Filter by `min_access_level` = maintainer (or higher) if you want to export whole projects.
2. Use the [Project export API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_import_export.html) to trigger a project export for each project you're a member of, and you're a maintainer (or higher).
3. For all other projects where you have a lower role, or where it's public, you could still use `git clone` for the repositories by storing the `ssh_url_to_repo` or `http_url_to_repo` from the Projects API and running through each.

   - For all other parts of a project, you could store the JSON version to recreate them later if you want to go through the hassle. For example, for issues, use the [Issues API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html).